# How to create extension activation commands that holds on restart

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create an extension that have two commands **Activate** and **Deactivate**. My question is: how to make it persist, so when I restart the editor the extension will remember if it is active or inactive?

One idea that come into my mind is to set a Boolean variable on configuration that I can change by commands and check it every time the editor starts, but it not seems a good approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ExtensionContext](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#ExtensionContext). The *workspaceState* property persists extension-specific data on a per-workspace basis, while the *globalState* property persists extension-specific data regardless of the workspace.

Comment: I don't know if I used it as I should but works, if you wanna see =)  https://github.com/xfilipe/keyboard-sounds/blob/master/src/extension.ts